# IntelliJ IDEA Git graph

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have IDEA Ultimate 13.1.3 and it does not show the branch graph in Version control window.
[image]

How can I enable it?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Jetbrain should show a default.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see that in the changes view (ALT+9 on windows)

Menu :

View > Tool Windows > Changes

or

VCS > Show Changes View

Then go to the log tab

you'll see the git changes committed in all the branches of the local and remote repositories.

More info at : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/log-tab.html